# How do I call a function with an array of strings as a parameter?

Tags: arrays, swift, function, sprite-kit

I have an array of strings that I'm trying to use in a function

```
var PostionRotation:Array = ["100,45,0.4","305,45,-0.2","505,45,0.3","705,45,-0.1","905,45,0.2"]

func loadSprite(ArrayOfPositions:[String],NameOfSprite:String,SpriteTextureName:String)
{
    // pass in a array for the positions and rotations of the sprites
    // string for spritename
    // string for spritetexturename
    for Position in 0...ArrayOfPositions.count
    {
    var tempstring = ArrayOfPositions[Position ]as String//takes a string ie: 143,628,0.6
    var tempStringarray : [String] = tempstring.componentsSeparatedByString(",") // adds each item seperated by , to an array
    let XPos = CGFloat((tempStringarray[0] as NSString).floatValue)// exstracts the x cord
    let YPos = CGFloat((tempStringarray[1] as NSString).floatValue)//exstracts the y cord
    let Rot = CGFloat((tempStringarray[1] as NSString).floatValue)//exstracts the zrotation
    let SpriteName =  SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: SpriteTextureName) // add variable with texture
        SpriteName.name = NameOfSprite + String(Position + 1)// gives it a name + number ted1 etc
        SpriteName.position = CGPoint( x: XPos, y: YPos)// gets position from array
        SpriteName.zPosition = 2
        SpriteName.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 100)
        addChild(SpriteName)
    }
}
```

How do I call the function?

I've tried:

```
 loadSprite(PostionRotation, NameOfSprite: "frog", SpriteTextureName: "frog001")

 loadSprite(PostionRotation[String], NameOfSprite: "frog", SpriteTextureName: "frog001")
```

Comment: You're doing it right, with the first example.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
loadSprite(PostionRotation, NameOfSprite: "frog", SpriteTextureName: "frog001")
```

Here is a Playground sample that call a global function with a String array as a parameter:

```
import UIKit

func testFunc(posList:[String]) -> String
{
    var s = ""

    for pos in posList
    {
        s = s + " --- " + pos
    }

    return s
}

var PostionRotation:Array = ["100,45,0.4","305,45,-0.2","505,45,0.3","705,45,-0.1","905,45,0.2"]


var result = "result: " + testFunc(PostionRotation)
```

Copy it in Playground, and play with it :-)

Comment: hi Nicolas sorry thats what i meant to put have edited to show that thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

its my fault it should be

```
var PostionRotation = ["100,45,0.4","305,45,-0.2","505,45,0.3","705,45,-0.1","905,45,0.2"]
```

then this works

```
    loadSprite(PostionRotation, NameOfSprite: "frog", SpriteTextureName: "frog001")
```